# How to remove duplicate value in array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got data like this :

```
data = [
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1,
            3,
            3,
            4,
            2,
            2,
            1,
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1,
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 3,
        "hashtag_id": [
            3,
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 4,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1,
            3,
            4
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 5,
        "hashtag_id": 1
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 6,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1,
            4
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to remove duplicate value in `hashtag_id` if its exist.

this is what i expected :

```
data = [
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1,
            3,
            4,
            2,
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 3,
        "hashtag_id": [
            3,
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 4,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1,
            3,
            4
        ]
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 5,
        "hashtag_id": 1
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 6,
        "hashtag_id": [
            1,
            4
        ]
    }
]
```

I was trying with this :

```
data = data.map(item => {
        item.hashtag_id = [...new Set(item.hashtag_id)]
        return item
      })
```

But got error :

```
"number 1 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"
```

What is wrong with that ?

Please tell me if you need more information to solve that problem if it's still not enough

Comment: One of the `hashtag_id` values is not an array so fix that to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the item before the last, `hashtag_id` is a number instead of an array of numbers. Since a number isn't an iterable, you can't make a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of it causing the error.

To account for the possibility of `hashtag_id` being a number, do this:

```js
data = data.map((item) => {
    item.hashtag_id = Array.isArray(item.hashtag_id) ? [...new Set(item.hashtag_id)] : item.hashtag_id;
    return item;
})
```

Comment: ohh thanks, I wasn't noticed if my value has a number value instead of array of numbers. It was working now. Thanks

Comment: Great it helped. Please remember to mark this as the correct answer. Thanks!